# Можно ли сказать: профессиональное качество?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Меня интересует можно ли использовать эпитет "профессиональное" по отношению к качеству.

Answer (score 1):

Высокое качество часто связывают с понятием *профессионализма* (положительная характеристика представителя какой-либо профессии) или *профессиональных условий* создания чего-либо, однако его позитивная оценка однозначно не следует из прилагательного "*профессиональный*" (связанный с причастностью представителя некой *профессии* к изготовлению чего-л.) - для этого требуется контекст. *В частных случаях* так говорить можно. Например, "**профессиональное качество** телевизионной (видео-) **съёмки**" указывает на то, что *качество отснятого материала* явно отличается от получаемого в любительских условиях, по причине того, что при профессиональной съёмке, как известно, используется хорошая аппаратура, обязательно штатив, правильно расположены микрофоны и т. п. (даже проф. качества персонала этого не заменят). В другом случае, напр. "профессиональный сбор белых грибов" не будет ассоциироваться с высоким качеством собранного; вряд ли полезно рекламировать и "*варенье профессионального качества*". Поэтому в самом *общем случае* сочетание "*профессиональное качество*" выглядит **неубедительно**, как попытка заменить простое слово "хорошее" или "высокое/высочайшее" (качество) канцелярским эпитетом.

Answer (score 1):

**Меня интересует можно ли использовать эпитет "профессиональное" по отношению к качеству.**

Зависит от контекста, в котором употреблено слово "качество". О человеке можно сказать, что **он обладает высокими профессиональными качествами** (педагог, например). Здесь речь идёт о чертах/свойствах человека. Вот пример контекста, в котором эпитет "профессиональное" не может быть использован:

**Шахматист пожертвовал качество*, чтобы осложнить игру.**

*Качество в шахматах — это разница в ценности между тяжёлой и лёгкой фигурой.

Comment: Действительно, во множественном числе чьи-нибудь _профессиональные качества_ можно даже заклеймить как "никудышные". В единственном же числе это сочетание воспринимается как попытка расхвалить и продать какую-то услугу.

Comment: @Alex_ander Мне так не кажется. Слово "качество" в значении "отличительный признак" употребляется реже, чем в значении "степень достоинства" (значения взял из словаря), поэтому возникает иногда путаница. Именно этим был вызван вопрос, я думаю.